# Latitude / Longitude for MediaStore video in Android 10

Tags: android, video, geolocation

I'm developing a picture / video organizer for Android, which will let users filter on Country / Area. To support this I access Latitude & Longitude info from the images I get from MediaStore. In Android 10, for "privacy reasons" this info was made less accessible, and we have to get it using ExifInterface. This works fine for images, but not for videos. Does anyone know how to get this info for videos?
FURTHER INFO
For both MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns and MediaStore.Videos.VideoColumns, the columns latitude and longitude are marked as deprecated and set to null, with the instruction that we should use ExifInterface.GetLatLong to retrieve them. For images, this works. For videos, this returns false and the values are null (on the phone, the geographic location for the video is shown, so the info is there.)
Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: On some devices the exif header of the jpg file does not contain latitude, longitude. Instead the Camera app uses the MediaStore only. If you make an organiser be shure you can read all.

Comment: I can hardly imagine that a Camera app would store longitude, lattitude both in exif header of jpg and in mediastore. If there are such devices then please tell.

Comment: Blackapps thanks for replying - I've added further info to my post now to hopefully make clear what my problem is!

Comment: Do your videos have an exif header to begin with? You could have informed us. https://superuser.com/questions/1036704/is-there-something-like-exif-for-video

Comment: Just to say, I have submitted a documentation bug report for this.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the answer. You have to use MediaMetadataRetriever for video. That worked.

Whoever did the online documentation for the MediaStore clearly cut and pasted the info from the Image section to the Video section without checking that it worked! Poor.